# TFS2013 Fails to Deserialize Parameters containing "$/"

Tags: tfs

I'm using the TFS 2013 XAML Build Process Template and have some parameters that contain TFS paths (i.e. start with `$/`) and the build immediately fails when deserializing the parameters.

The only workaround I have is to use `$\/` but this gets pushed through as it is literally, breaking things that expect `$/`. Is there any way I can escape the strings properly?

e.g.

```
Post-build script arguments: -Path1 "$/MyProject/MySolution.sln" -Path2 $/MyProject/NuGet"
MSBuild arguments: /p:PackageOutputDir="$/MyProject/NuGet"
```

This is causing the following type of exception when I try to run a build:

```
Exception Message: TF401070: Could not deserialize the JSON string provided. Details:
After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: \. Path 'PostActionScriptArguments', line 1, position 449. (type BuildParameterSerializationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter.set_Json(String value)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: \. Path 'PostActionScriptArguments', line 1, position 449. (type JsonReaderException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue()
```

Comment: You should specify TF_BUILD environment variables in the MSBuild Arguments of your build definition, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: @Cece-MSFT the paths I'm using aren't supplied by TF_BUILD environment variables. I need to supply TFS paths that aren't supplied by TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY.